# Different php versions

Tags: php, terminal, macports

Apache and my terminal are using two different php versions. The one that I installed via macports and the other is the one that comes with the mac.

My phpconfig tells me is using the mac one:

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path    /etc
>
> Loaded Configuration File /etc/php.ini

And the Terminal version is using the one installed via macports:

> php --ini
>
> Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /opt/local/etc/php5
>
> Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
>
> Scan for additional .ini files in: /opt/local/var/db/php5
>
> Additional .ini files parsed:      /opt/local/var/db/php5/intl.ini

How can I say to apache to load the macports version of php, and how can I change the "Loaded Configuration File" which is actually none?

UPDATE:
I solved how to Load the Conf file:

Copy the mac php.ini into /opt/local/etc/php5 (the "Configuration File (php.ini) Path") :

> sudo cp /etc/php.ini /opt/local/etc/php5/

and how to change the php.ini that Apache is reading:

> sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Just after the LoadModule php5_module add the line:
PHPINIDir "/opt/local/etc/php5/php.ini"

But I still have two different php running. So the question is how to say to apache to load my macports php?

UPDATE 2:

I've been reading for a solution and this is changing the path of the LoadModule php5 in the http.conf:

> LoadModule php5_module /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_php54.so

But actually I have no mod_php54.so in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

The MacPorts documentation has a good step-by-step for setting up a MAMP install. I found it really useful when I went through the process. 
https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/MAMP
Jump down to step four and look at the 'Register PHP with Apache' section. There are also quite a few other steps that you might need to study. It looks like you've gotten some of them already.

Comment: Links can be helpful as supplemental information, but [link-only answers are strongly discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/228805). Also, an answer should provide an actual solution to the issue raised in the question, not just reference material or general advice on how to go about finding a solution. Please include a summary of the linked information that's relevant to the question, and explain specifically how it resolves the issue.